# Excel: Check if column A has any values from Column B, and delete that value from Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel: Check if column A has any values from Column B, and delete that value from Column A](https://superuser.com/questions/520135/excel-check-if-column-a-has-any-values-from-column-b-and-delete-that-value-fro)

So I have two columns in Excel with these values suppose:

Column A   |   Column B 
12    | 626
241  | 129
35    | 412
412  | 88
532  | 663
626
723
88
932

What formula should I use to delete the values 88, 626 and 412 from Column A (applying the formula then going to Goto > Goto Special > Errors... and deleting rows)

Can't quite get this sorted at all!

Comment: You could put a formula in column C like: "=NOT(MATCH(B2,A:A,0))" that would provide an error value in the proper rows, but you would still need to delete the values one-by-one.