# Excel: Check if column A has any values from Column B, and delete that value from Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have two columns in Excel with these values suppose:

```
Column A | Column B
---------|---------
12       | 626
241      | 129
35       | 412
412      | 88
532      | 663
626      |
723      |
88       |
932      |
```

What formula should I use to delete the values 88, 626 and 412 from Column A (applying the formula then going to <kbd>Goto</kbd> > <kbd>Goto Special</kbd> > <kbd>Errors...</kbd> and deleting rows)

Can't quite get this sorted at all!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (your case for example), errors may be useful. There's function `NA()`, which will display `#N/A` error in a cell. Combining it with `IF` and `COUNTIF` will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into C1, and copy down to C2:C9.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)>0, NA())
```

If value of A1 is found in column B:B, show `#N/A` in C1.

And then "applying the formula then going to <kbd>Goto</kbd> > <kbd>Goto Special</kbd> > <kbd>Errors...</kbd> and deleting rows".